Need Help for building two constraints in MIP model
Really need help for building two constraints with MIP model, I have written the required information and variable information on the diagram below.

The way I think of it now is to use two identifiers $A$ and $B$ to indicate whether $a$ and $b$ are $0$, if $a=0$ then $A=0$, if $b=0$ then $B=0$; And then I change the equation to
$$(e*A + f*B) * x_1 \ge V * \max\{A, B\} \tag{3} $$
$$G + (e*A + f*B) * x_2 = 1 \tag{4}$$
To achieve the purpose that $G$ is controlled by $a$ and $b$, and $x_1$, $x_2$ is $0$ when both $a$ and $b$ are $0$
the problem is, When I convert the equation format, I notice that a ZeroDivisionError occurs once both $A$ and $B$ are $0$.
$$x_1 \ge V * \frac{\max\{A, B\}}{e*A + f*B} \tag{3'}$$
$$x_2 = \frac{1-G}{e*A + f*B} \tag{4'}$$
However, when I do programming using scipy.minimize, the program does not report errors and gives results that conform to the constraints，which confuses me.
Logically, when the values of $A$ and $B$ are both $0$, the constraint (3') and (4') will fail, so why does it work?

Constraints are slightly different from equations as the solver try to find a feasible solution that satisfies the constraint. With $A,B = 0$ constr $3$ turns to $V*0 \le 0$ & $4$ to $G=1$. Absent any other information constrs $1,2$ then decide the values of $x$

@Sutanu Majumdar So your point is because of slover's features, constrs 3、 4 don't work if A,B = 0, does that mean? x1 and x2 are not restricted to zero, right？So if I add a positive coefficient to the minimizing objective function for x1 ，x2, say obj=c1x1+c2x2+... cn*xn, assuming there are no other constraints, will x1 and x2 be reduced to 0 because of the optimization objective? (Assuming that x1 and x2 are always greater than or equal to 0)

@CangWangu, which kinds of variables are $e, f$?

@A.Omidi, e and f are two constants, and the way my program is designed is to go through range(5) twice, pick two numbers as the values of e and f, and then solve the corresponding model in the solver
